# Shrink the size of 2D array by removing specific rows and columns from it

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm learning C, and I can't find a solution to this problem.

If I have a matrix of random size filled with '*'(star), '-'(horizontal bar), '|'(vertical bar),'+'(plus sign) and I want to remove every row that has a '-', every column that has a '|', every row and column in which there is a '+'.

How would i reduce the size of the matrix so that when i print the remaining '*'(star) there are no rows and columns between them that were removed?

For example:

```
char mat[3][3] = {{'|', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*'}};
```

The output would be:

```
**
**
**
```

Another example:

```
char mat[3][3] = {{'*', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '+', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*'}};
```

The output would be:

```
**
**
```

Larger matrix:

```
char mat[4][5] = {{'*', '|', '*', '|', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '+', '*', '-', '*'}
                  {'*', '*', '*', '*', '-'}};
```

The output would be:

```
***
***
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot shrink a statically defined array as the one in your example. You can mark a column or a row though, so that when the printing phase comes around, you simply skip the invalidated column(s) and row(s).

Example for the `'|'` case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3
#define M 3

void invalidate_col(char mat[N][M], const int col)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        mat[i][col] = 'n';
    }
}

void print(char mat[N][M])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if(mat[i][j] != 'n')
                printf("%c ", mat[i][j]);        
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}

int main(void) {
    char mat[N][M] = {{'|', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*'},
                  {'*', '*', '*'}};
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if(mat[i][j] == '|')
            {
                invalidate_col(mat, j);
            }
        }
    }
    print(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
* * 
* * 
* *
```

---

If you really need to delete these column(s) and row(s), then you need to dynamically allocate the matrix (check [my example](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/)), use `realloc()` to shrink it accordingly, and at the end `free()` to dellocate that memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite simple.

One of brutal methods is 1) scan the whole input matrix and find the numbers of rows and columns that should be removed according to those '-', '|', '+' found in the input matrix, say they are r, c, 2) the numbers of rows and columns in the output matrix can be inferred, which are x - r, y - c, assuming x, y are the numbers of rows and columns in the input matrix.